# Prove that every lattice homomorphism is order preserving but converse is not true.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

If $(L,*,+)$ and $(S,\cdot,\vee)$ are two lattices, a mapping $g\colon L\to S$ is called a lattice homomorphism from $L$ to $S$ if for any $a,b \in L$ we have $g(a*b) = g(a) \cdot g(b)$ and $g(a+b) = g(a) \vee g(b)$. How to prove that every lattice homomorphism is order preserving but converse is not true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Given $a,b\in L,$ we have $a\le_L b$ iff $a*b=a$ iff $a+b=b$. The order relation on $S$ is similarly defined.

For a counterexample to the converse, see [this picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Monotonic_but_nonhomomorphic_map_between_lattices.gif).

Comment: How do you define the partial order relations in the lattices in the picture?

Comment: @Manjoy By $a<b$ if there is an upward path from $a$ to $b.$

Comment: what I meant was how you would like to describe the order relation in language. For example the first lattice could be described as the set of all positive divisors of $6$. Similarly the 2nd could be the set of all primes from $3$ to $7$ with usual less than or equal to relation in which $0_M=3, 1_M=7$. But if I demonstrate the lattices in this way, it's becoming quite tough to make a function $g:L\to M$ explicitly.

Comment: @Manjoy I might describe them as the power set of the two element set $\{u,v\}$ (with $\cap$ and $\cup$ as the lattice operations, $\subseteq$ as the order relation) and the set of cardinalities of subsets of said two-element set (with pairwise minimum and pairwise maximum as the lattice operations, the usual order relation). The counterexample function sends each subset of $\{u,v\}$ to its cardinality.

Comment: great thinking. +1